# Call static method in Spring @Query

Tags: java, spring, repository, spring-data-jpa, spring-el

I am trying to create a Base repository so all my Repositories that implement the interface will have a custom behavior, so here is my class so far:

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface BaseRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> extends PagingAndSortingRepository<T, ID> {

    @Query("Select t from #{#entityName} t where t.code = '#{T(com.route.to.class).someStaticMethod()}'")
    Page<T> findAll(Pageable pageable);
}
```

So in the someStaticMethod() I just return a Random number for the momment for testing purposes. In the future it will have the logic to retrieve the number.

The issue I am facing is that the method someStaticMethod() is only called once. So for example, if the random number is 2 when the application starts, it will not change this value on the following calls.

Is there a way that every time the findAll() method its called it actually executes the someStaticMethod() so that it updates the value?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What is that static method supposed to return?

Comment: It is a string based on some logic I will implement based on the actual user that is authenticaded.

Comment: This shouldn't be called by the query. It should be called by your business logic (and not be static, to benefit of Spring beans, injection, etc.). And the result should be passed as argument to your query method. Repositories should be just that: repositories. Business logic belongs in the service layer.